# Google API to get Snapshot using filter,

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, snapshot

I have written following code, which return me list of Snapshot, which have particular string, but this does not return snapshots whose Size is 0,

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/list

```
this  API have following attributes:
```

- project_id
- filter

> I am trying to put some filter based on regular expression which will
>   match all snapshot which have "intance-snap" in there name.

```
 def snapshotlist():  
        query = "name eq <string>.*"  
        snaplist = compute.snapshots().list(project=project,filter=query).execute()  
        snaplist = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(snaplist))  
        for snap in snaplist['items']:  
            print(snap['name'])
```

Above code does not return Snapshots, which have size 0, is there way to get all snapshots, regardless of there **SIZE** ?

Comment: From the documentation of the optional parameter's filter attribute, **The comparison operator must be either `=`, `!=`, `>`, or `<`.** So no, you cannot perform a query similar to what is done with the Drive API, e.g. `q: "name contains 'some string'"` Collect your list of Snapshots and then use your language's string and regex methods to filter the output.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer to the question for the benefit of the community?

Comment: @tehhowch can you please look again, I have written code for this, but its not resulting full result.

Comment: query = "name eq cp.*" , when I used this, I got list of Snapshot in response:
cptest15305994871
cptest15305994872
cptest15305994873
cptest15305994875
cptest15305994876
cptest153059948811
cptest153059948812

Comment: So what's the issue? You have results, so your question is solved.

Comment: @tehhowch API is not return all snapshots,  to be more specific snapshots having size 0B are not returned

Comment: @kishan rai How are you having snapshots of size 0B ? I tried to reproduce and make a couple of snapshots within 10 minutes without changing anything on the VM, and the snapshots still have a size that is not equal to 0B. Could you share more details regarding this or where you see these snapshots that are 0B?

Comment: @PhilippSh hostsnap-4052639891871519314-153209332936 testvm37-disk02 Jul 20, 2018, 7:01:31 PM 10 GB 0 B 
 hostsnap-2621490148131762793-153209332711 testvm11-disk02 Jul 20, 2018, 7:01:30 PM 10 GB 0 B 
 hostsnap-1041571056610202227-153209332930 testvm30-disk02 Jul 20, 2018, 7:01:23 PM 10 GB 0 B 
 hostsnap-4620844806498964244-153209332944 testvm45-disk02 Jul 20, 2018, 7:01:21 PM 10 GB 0 B 
 hostsnap-8397883787275694665-153209332820 testvm20-disk02 Jul 20, 2018, 7:01:21 PM 10 GB 0 B

THIS IS DETAILFROM MY CONSOLE WHERE I CREATED SNAPSHOT, USING SCRIPT

Comment: May you run this command *gcloud compute snapshots list --log-http* in your console and confirm the snapshot storageBytes are 0B?? And, **if so**, could you add a piece of your script in order to try to reproduce your issue and answer you properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Snapshot documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/list), for the optional parameter's `filter` attribute:

> The expression must specify the field name, a comparison operator, and the value that you want to use for filtering. The value must be a string, a number, or a boolean. **The comparison operator must be either `=`, `!=`, `>`, or `<`.**

While this means you cannot perform a query similar to what is done with the Drive API, e.g. `q: "name contains 'some string'"`, the `Snapshots#list` method still appears to support wildcard matching. If you are unable to successfully write the appropriate regex, then the solution is to collect your *entire* list of `Snapshot`s, and then use your language's string and regex methods to filter the output.

```
def get_matching_snapshots(projectId: str, query='',
                           fields='id,nextPageToken,warning,items(id,name,description)'):
    snaplist = []
    params = {project: projectId,
              filter: query,
              fields: fields}
    # Collect all pages of results
    request = compute.snapshots().list(**params)
    while request:
        response = request.execute()
        if 'items' in response:
            snaplist.extend(response['items'])
        if 'warning' in response:
            pprint(response['warning'])
        request = compute.snapshots().list_next(request, response)

    return snaplist

# Use 'filter' parameter to restrict on server side:
name_fragment = "some required part of the name"
q = f'name = "{name_fragment}.*"'
pprint(get_matching_snapshots("some project id", q))

# get all, then apply restrictions after retrieval:
all_snapshots = get_matching_snapshots("some project id")
matches = []
rgx = re.compile('some regex')
for snap in all_snapshots:
    # use rgx.match with the relevant snap property
    ...
```

You may find it beneficial to consult the Compute API's Python documentation, or to use the Python client's API Explorer:

- [`snapshots()` PyDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.snapshots.html)
- [`snapshots().list()` Python API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.snapshots.list)